Is there a way to make RS232 communication with fluke8846a faster for measurement?
I’m using Fluke 8846A for measuring current in a setup where the current range is set to 10A. I’m using MEASure method to read value from Fluke 8846a using RS232 communication at baud rate of 115200 with one stop bit and no parity in remote mode. The time taken from the query to receiving the response is roughly 275ms which is a bit high for my application. I would ideally want it to be less than or equal to 50ms. Is there a way to make this communication faster?
Also I’m trying to synchronize this reading from another source so I want to collect data by single trigger which I think MEASure method provides.
Code snippet used for profiling:
query_msg = "MEAS:volt:dc? 10\r"
ser.write(query_msg)
#Receive data until <CR><LF>
print(time())
received_data = ser.read(17)
print(time())  

Time printed(s) in terminal:
1717717621.2261405
1717717621.5009155
I expect the time response to be faster

"I’m using Fluke 8846A for measuring current ..." - Then why are you using an example from the manual for measuring voltage? "Is there a way to make this communication faster?" - Only if you use the instrument properly. The bottleneck is not "RS232 communication" in your "code snippet", but rather the MEASure? command which encapsulates a instrument configuration and then the A-to-D trigger, capture, and conversion. Study the section titled Optimizing System Speed for I/O Operation in the manual.
